# Задача. Динамический массив. C++

Tags: c++

> Даны действительные числа . Получить действительную квадратную матрицу порядка n<8, элементами которой являются числа , расположенные в ней по схеме:
>
> ```
> ----------
>          |
> ----------
> |
> ----------
>          |
> ----------
> |
> ---------->
> ```
>
> Матрица размещается в памяти динамически с помощью операции new, значение n вводится по запросу с клавиатуры. В конце работы программы освободить выделенную память. Вывести полученную матрицу.

Comment: схема криво вышла, там типа змейкой

Comment: @fastname, а в чем проблема?

Рассматриваете матрицу как одномерный массив (указатель на первый элемент матрицы) и тогда адресуетесь к элементу `i,j` так:


      a[i * n + j]  // a -- это указатель на matr[0][0]

Comment: @fastname: Прикольное задание. Продолжайте информировать нас, нам очень интересно.

Comment: @avp: `a[(i | 0x1) * n + (i & 0x1) ? ~j : j]` вроде бы